# fopen error when trying to upload a CSV file

Tags: php, fopen

When trying to import a CSV, it errors with `Warning: fopen(/test-spreadsheet.csv) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/.../public_html/wp-content/plugins/bulk-upload/import-response.php on line 49`

It also echo's `path: /test spreadsheet.csv` where I have echo'd the following:

```
echo "path: " . $file_path;
```

import-response.php

```
    require_once("zip-util.php");
    require_once("script-generator.php");

    if ($_POST["verify_bulk_upload_postback"] == "Y")
    {
        if ($_POST["erase_all_data"])
        {
            $query = new WP_Query(array(
                    "post_type" => "people",
                    "posts_per_page" => -1
                ));

            $to_delete = array();
            //echo "<strong>Existed</strong><br /><br />";

            foreach ($query->posts as $post)
            {        
                $to_delete[] = $post->ID;

                if ($post->ID > 0)
                {                
                    $attachment_query = new WP_Query(array(
                        "post_parent" => $post->ID,
                        "posts_per_page" => -1,
                        "post_type" => "attachment"
                    ));

                    foreach($attachment_query->posts as $attachment)
                    {
                        $to_delete[] = $attachment->ID;
                    }
                }                
            }

            foreach ($to_delete as $id)
            {
                //echo "Deleting post with id " . $id . "<br />";
                wp_delete_post($id, true);
            }

        ?><div class="updated"><p><strong><?php _e('Existing Diamonds Deleted'); ?></strong></p></div><?php
        }

        $file_path = $uploaddir . '/' . basename($_FILES['csv_file']['name']);
echo "path: " . $file_path;
        $file = fopen($file_path, 'r');
//echo phpinfo();
        ScriptGenerator::generate($file);

        fclose($file);

        //echo "<br /><strong>Extracting images&hellip;</strong><br /><br />";

        $upload_dir_info = wp_upload_dir();
echo $upload_dir_info["path"];
        ZipUtil::unzip($_FILES["zip_file"]["name"], $upload_dir_info["path"]);

    ?>
    <div class="updated"><p><strong id="status">
        <img src="/wp-content/plugins/bulk-upload/loader.gif" />
        <?php _e('Uploading...'); ?>
    </strong></p></div>

    <?php /* if (count($error_rows) > 0) { ?>
    <div class="error">
        <?php foreach ($error_rows as $error_row) { ?>
            <p>Failed on: <?php print_r($error_row); ?></p>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php } */ ?>

<?php

    }

?>
```

zip-util.php

```
<?php
class ZipUtil
{
    public static function unzip($zip_file, $destination)
    {
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $res = $zip->open($zip_file);

        if ($res === TRUE)
        {
            $zip->extractTo($destination);
            $zip->close();
            echo "Images were unzipped.<br />";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<strong>Failed to unzip images. Please check file permissions.</strong><br />";
    echo "Could not unzip $filename-- ".$res;
    return false;
        }
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: Write `echo "path: " . realpath($file_path);` and check is there `test spreadsheet.csv` is in this directory?

Comment: Thanks @Winston it just outputs `path: ` :(

Comment: @Winston: any idea what it could be?

Comment: @Winston: it doesn't upload the file in the directory :( dir is empty.. dir echos as  
 /home/.../public_html/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/test-spreadsheet.csv

Comment: OK. Write `echo dirname(__FILE__);` in `import-response.php` file and show me path that will be output. Also write here path from root dir (where is `index.php`) to `test spreadsheet.csv` file and show it too.

Comment: @Winston: That echo'd `/home/.../public_html/wp-content/plugins/bulk-upload` - index.php is in /home/.../public_html/wp-content/themes/.../index.php - test spreadsheet.csv isn't anywhere to be found in the directories :(

Comment: Try like this `$file_path = "../../plugins/bulk-upload/test spreadsheet.csv";`

Comment: `Warning: fopen(../../plugins/bulk-upload/test spreadsheet.csv) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/.../public_html/wp-content/plugins/bulk-upload/import-response.php on line 53`

Comment: :D Now try in import-response.php write like this `$file_path = "../../uploads/2013/02/test-spreadsheet.csv";`
Your csv file is in `uploads/2013/02/test-spreadsheet.csv` right?

Comment: @Winston: That's the thing, it doesn't upload the file. I'll upload it there and try again. But really want it uploaded as I run the code.

Comment: @Winston: Also, updating code and uploading the file produced error `Warning: fopen(../../uploads/2013/02/test-spreadsheet.csv) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/.../public_html/wp-content/plugins/bulk-upload/import-response.php on line 53`

Comment: Hmm. Can you write path from root to `import-response.php` and from root to `test spreadsheet.csv`?

Comment: import-response.php is `/home/.../public_html/wp-content/plugins/bulk-upload/import-response.php` and test spreadsheet.csv is `/home/.../public_html/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/test spreadsheet.csv` (/home/.../public_html/ can be replaced with http://www.mydomain.com/)

Comment: I don't now why it not find file. But this code should work... try again `$file_path = "../../uploads/2013/02/test spreadsheet.csv"` if again will be error, check the filename of csv

Comment: @winston: same error :( `failed to open stream: No such file or directory in...`

Answer (score 0):

This line:

`$file_path = $uploaddir . '/' . basename($_FILES['csv_file']['name']);`

I have a feeling that `$uploaddir` is not valid at this point so instead of going to the proper directory, it's going to the root directory (/, instead of /home...)

Hope this makes sense..

You may just need this: `$ud = wp_upload_dir(); $uploaddir = $ud["path"];` on the line above it.

Comment: Thanks but now `Warning: fopen(Array/test-spreadsheet.csv)...`

Comment: I have now amended this Dave, but I am not sure if it will work.. but I think it is correct to assume that `$uploaddir` is wrong, but what it should be I am not sure I'm afraid..

Comment: Nice... getting there! Now `Warning: fopen(/home/.../public_html/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/test-spreadsheet.csv)`

Comment: Well, I don't fully understand what is going on, but I suggest you `print_r($_FILES)` to see if the directory of the stored file is in there, theoretically it should be, but don't hold me to this!

Comment: `Array ( [csv_file] => Array ( [name] => test-spreadsheet.csv [type] => text/comma-separated-values [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpAQk652 [error] => 0 [size] => 162 ) [zip_file] => Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 ) ) ` I've edited code from `name` to `tmp_name`

Comment: Okay, instead of using `$file_path = ...` use `$filepath = $_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'];` And that may get it further.

Comment: Still the same :( but it's saying `Warning: ZipArchive::open() [ziparchive.open]: Empty string as source in /home/.../public_html/wp-content/plugins/bulk-upload/zip-util.php on line 7
Failed to unzip images. Please check file permissions.
Could not unzip -- `